# how to make nav buttons stay together when the screen changes size

Tags: css, menu, nav

Okay, this is difficult to explain. If you look at the sample I put up at http://granthoneymoon.com/temp3.html you can see 4 nav buttons to the right of the logo.

What I want is for the nav buttons to be evenly spread among the space to the right of the logo, and as the browser window gets smaller the buttons get closer together. But, at a certain point, once the browser gets so small that the buttons would overlap it would push the whole menu underneath the logo.

Right now I have the buttons inline to the right of the logo, but as the browser gets smaller it just pushes one button at a time to the next line instead of the buttons getting closer together.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

scale the buttons reponsively: e.g.

```
img.button{
       width:17%
       height :auto;
}
```

Comment: where would that be specifically in the css that I have? I don't have any img for the buttons, instead they are div's with a background (so that I can change the background image when the mouse hovers over it).

Comment: i'm in the middle of doing a fiddle for you

Comment: If you look at the #mainnav li css you'll see I do have the width specified at 20%.

Comment: i only put in one small image

Comment: THanks for the time you put into that! Unfortunately, I can only see one of the buttons, the others don't show up. Also, the logo shrinks in size as the window changes size, and I'm not seeing the buttons change with the browser window change.

Comment: they do shrink though on browser resize - all the images it's responsive design

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the bottom of you CSS Sheet

Using @CSS Media Tags it will change the #header ID to max-width of 627px  when the screen reaches width: 1077px

//CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1077px) {
    #header{
        max-width: 627px;
    }
}
```

Comment: All that seems to do is keep the nav buttons fixed no matter what size the browser is. I need the buttons to get closer together as the window gets smaller, until the buttons themselves get to the min-width in which case I need the entire mainnav to go under the logo (all the buttons at once)

Comment: Hmm...something seems to not be working right. Check out http://granthoneymoon.html/temp3.html and change the size. When really wide the background disappears, when it gets smaller one of the buttons moves down to the second row, and when it gets even smaller it goes back to the top and the background comes back, but the buttons don't get closer together nor do they move over to the second line even when the browser gets to smart phone width. :-/

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the problems [Flexbox](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox-1/) was created to solve.

Here is a good resource to get started:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The gotcha with Flexbox is that because it’s new browser support is somewhat limited. See which browsers can use it here:
http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

I added comments below to explain what each line is doing. Let me know if you have any questions!

```css
/* on all elements, reset any browser
   added default margin and padding */
* { margin:0; padding:0 }


body {
  /* make it pretty */
  font-family: 'Palatino', serif;
  font-style: italic;
}


header {
  /* set flex-parent, makes direct
     children flex-children */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  /* direct childen of the header
     should wrap */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  /* make it pretty */
  background: darkblue;
}


header #logo {
  /* as a flex child, grow and
     shrink as needed, use base-width
     of 200px */
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 200px;
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  
  /* set logo height */
  height: 70px;
  
  /* make it pretty */
  background: lightgrey;
  
  /* make this element also a flex-parent */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  /* direct childen (in this case, the :before)
     should be vertically centered inside of logo */
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* direct childen (in this case, the :before)
     should be horizontally centered inside of logo */
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
header #logo:before {
  /* add descriptive text to this box */
  content: 'Logo';
}


header nav {
  /* as a flex child, grow and shrink as needed,
     use current width as base width */
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  
  /* change padding not to add to overall width */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* set left and right padding to 10% of
     available space */
  padding: 0 10%;
  
  /* make this element also a flex-parent */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  /* direct childen (in this case, the links)
     should be vertically centered inside of this element */
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  /* direct childen (in this case, the links)
     should be horizontally centered inside of this element */
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


header nav a {
  /* as a flex child, never ever grow and shrink,
     use curremt width as base width */
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  
  /* change padding not to add to overall width */
  box-sizing: border-box;

  /* hard code width and height */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  /* add 10px of margin to top, right, bottom, and left */
  margin: 10px;
  
  /* make it pretty */
  background: linear-gradient(cyan, blue);
  border-radius: 10%;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* make this element also a flex-parent */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  /* direct childen (in this case, the link text)
     should be vertically centered inside of this element */
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <figure id="logo"></figure>
  <nav>
    <a href="">Link One</a>
    <a href="">Link Two</a>
    <a href="">Link Three</a>
    <a href="">Link Four</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Editable Demo: [http://jsbin.com/zavawudaye/3](http://jsbin.com/zavawudaye/3/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: I'm trying to use the flexbox, but I'm noticing in your example the logo part of the header also shrinks. I'm wanting the logo container to be a fixed width. Is that not possible?

Comment: It's totally possible but it looks odd when it wraps. Set a width on a `header #logo` and use `flex: 0 0 auto`

Comment: As far as browser support goes, I would test this in the browsers you want that don’t support flexbox then tweak your CSS to make those browsers not look broken but not necessarily do all the fancy collapsing flexbox allows. When a browser doesn't understand a CSS property it ignores it meaning you don't even have to target non-flexbox browsers separately to make your non-flexbox header. Just make sure that your flexbox properties come last in the rule so that they take precedence in browsers that do support flexbox.

Comment: I tried to do the flex box with what I have and it doesn't seem to be working. You can see it at http://granthoneymoon.com/flex_box_sample.html

BTW, I'm not worrying about the wrapping right now. I'll just use the @media for that. I'm just trying to get the mainnav buttons to spread out evenly in the space between the logo and the edge of the browser and continue to get closer together as the window shrinks.

Comment: Oh man. Why are you using an id of 'header' instead of the `<header>` tag? Why did you add the id `mainnav` to a `<nav>` element, are you expecting other nav elements in your header? You also don’t need unique classes on each of your links. If you, for some reason, need to special case every single one of your links, just use an attribute selector (e.g. `nav a[href*=profile]`).

Comment: I see you’re using pictures instead of text for your links. That will make your site difficult to scale to mobile and impossible for visually impaired users to use. Anyway, to your original question: You can’t see the links in your test page right now because you added floats to everything (never use floats for basic layout) and because for some reason you added a width of `478%` to your logo. Also, why did you wrap the logo `<img>` in a container `<div>`?